Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonItemReaderBuilder'
I'm working on a spring project with batch and initialized it with the following dependencies:
-spring web
-spring batch
-spring jpa
-mysql driver
Ifind so many problems concerning dependencies especially about the JsonItemReaderBuilder, please help me.
I tried to modify my pom.xml too many times but no result.
here is my BatchConfig.java:
package config;

import entity.DossierMutuelle;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.JsonItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonObjectReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    // Use StepBuilder directly without StepBuilderFactory
    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<DossierMutuelle> jsonItemReader() {
        JsonObjectReader<DossierMutuelle> jsonObjectReader = new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(DossierMutuelle.class);
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<DossierMutuelle>()
                .jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("dossiers.json"))
                .name("jsonItemReader")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return new StepBuilder("step1")  // Use StepBuilder directly
                .<DossierMutuelle, DossierMutuelle>chunk(10)
                .reader(jsonItemReader())
                .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println)) // Example Writer
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return new JobBuilder("job")  // Use JobBuilder directly
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}


and my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>GestionMutuelles</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GestionMutuelles</name>
    <description>GestionMutuelles</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot and Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson dependencies for JSON processing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version> <!-- Ensure you have the correct version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version> <!-- Ensure you have the correct version -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

